# Understanding MRC on ARM7

Tags: assembly, arm

I am new to ARM and trying to understand MRC instruction.

As I understood , MRC is to read Coprocessor registers and put it into main Core register.

Now Coprocessors are attached to main core and is used to control the memory subsystem of main core.How Coprocessors are attached to main core processor .Could anyone point to some good Digram?

Now this below instruction on arm7 cpu core

```
  /* workaround to disable secure state */
     mrc     p15, #0, r0, c1, c1, #0
     orr     r0, r0, #1
     mcr     p15, #0, r0, c1, c1, #0
     isb
```

Now I just couldn't find what is going on in mrc instruction here

1.First argument to mrc is coprocessor number(how p0 is different from p15).

2.Second Argument is opcode1 of coprocessor(Not sure about it).

3.Third argument is main core register(Ok with it).

4.fourth and fivth argumnet is co processor registers(Is result of c1,#0 is stored to c1 )?

5.Agin final Argument is opcode2 (Not sure about it).

Thanks

Comment: Please look at [coprocessor questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+is%3Aquestion+coprocessor).  Like [What is MRC command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688372/what-is-the-function-of-the-additional-coprocessor-register-of-the-mrc-command), [Peter Cockerell](http://www.peter-cockerell.net/aalp/html/app-a.html), etc.

Comment: The `MRC`/`MCR` instructions are generic.  You have to refer to specific documents.  **VFP**, **Neon**, and **CP15**.  The **CP15** is a catch all for things not built-in to the instruction set and is intended for **OS programmers**.  It **may** include **MMU**, *cache control*, *protection unit*, *fast context switch*, *write buffer*, *TrustZone*, *HyperVisor*, *Vector table*, etc.  **CP15** does not remain **backwards** compatible as the instruction set does.

Comment: Thanks @artlessnoise for these useful links.

Comment: did you mean ARMv7 instead of ARM7?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Coprocessor** in ARM is a misleading notion. It's shorthand for an optional piece of functionality that is not exposed via the core instruction set. ARM CPUs are modular. There are bits and pieces of CPU hardware that implementers of the architecture may or may not place on the chip. The memory management unit (MMU) is one example; there are others, such is the hardware debugging facility. Those are, indeed, identified by coprocessor number (`pXX`), so that more than one coprocessor can be present at the same time. The coprocessor number for MMU is traditionally p15. Coprocessors p0..p14 have nothing to do with memory management and may not be present. The debugging subsystem, for example, is p14.

The MRC and MCR commands are used to send commands to coprocessors. The mnemonic is, again, somewhat misleading - the effect of a command can be more than just a register move. It's more like MRC stands for "send a command to a coprocessor and get some data back" and MCR is "send a command to a coprocessor and pass some data along". Think of it that way. That's what the opcodes are for - that's the command to the coprocessor. Sometimes, a MCR/MRC command with a particular coproc # and opcode would even get separate mnemonic in the assembler (e. g. FPU commands).

The exact specifics of coprocessor opcodes and register numbers vary from one copropcessor to another. Since it's the MMU that you're interested in, read up on that particular one; it'll explain how do specific operations map to opcodes and coproc register numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Seva for your kind answer.May be dumb question but can I say Co-processor is not a physical entity and it just another set of instruction run and controls the various subsystem like MMU subsystem?Also could you please provide some docs where I can read what you have advised me to read.

Comment: like the cache and fpu, etc it is a physical entity.  You should be able to look at the technical reference manuals for the arm cores to see the optional straps you can use to enable/disable logic, etc.  Some of it though you won actually see though without having the arm logic itself.  Note the floating point units have traditionally just been coprocessors as well, you can tell that from the machine encoding of the instructions.

Comment: It's not a separate chip, but it's physical all right. It's an area on the CPU chip that implements the functionality.

Comment: Fine @Seva ,So is it right to say that MMU subsytem is one co-processor and fpu is another co-processor.Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It can actually be a **physically** different chip.  Early **ARMs** did come with lines that could connect a differently packaged *VFP*.  As today everyone wants things to be as small as possible, they are usually on the same *die*, but are at least separate [HDL source files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language), with signals from one module to the other.

Comment: @artlessnoise,Would you please confirm this understanding of mine that MMU itself is co-processor and fpu is other or MMU is connected to co-processor(which is physical entity) and this co-processor is specially built to control MMU subsystem.Same way fpu has one dedicated co-processor.

Comment: It is right to say that MMU subsystem is one co-processor and FPU is another co-processor.

Comment: That is mostly correct.  The **CP15** is more than the *MMU*; is it the **ARM** implementations extra features.  Normal *user space* should not need to touch the **CP15** code; whereas it is common/possible to use the other types of *co-processors* in *user* mode.  See: `ldc`, `cdp`, and `stc` as well as special purpose instructions.  [Heyrick's co-processor commands](http://www.heyrick.co.uk/assembler/coprocmnd.html) is a good reference as well.  Generally in all modern **ARMs**, Seva is right they are in the same chip.  However, as they are implemented as co-pro, it is often an *option*.